# Browse line range of file in GitHub with Magit

Tags: magit, github

Is it possible to select a range of code and open it in GitHub using Magit? I use the browse-at-remote package for this, but I wonder if this could be done from Magit. I'd like to navigate both from code selection and from a commit diff. Also, I'd like to be able to browse the master branch, even if I'm in a feature branch. Right now with browse-at-remote I have to manually replace the branch name with master in the GitHub URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The magit extension [`forge`](https://github.com/magit/forge) supports visiting certain things in a browser, but currently that is limited to issues, pull-requests, commits and the repository itself.

Files and even locations within files might be supported in the future, or not. While I think this would be nice to have I don't plan to work on it any time soon.

Comment: `forge-browse-commit` works like a charm, thank you!